# Sending POST data between Django apps

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, urllib2

I need to send POST request from one Django app to another under the same project. The request arrives, but without POST data.

Why is that? And how to send POST data properly?

**Sender part**, app 1 view:

```
def get_project_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            response = etl_post('get_data', [request.user.project.id], request.POST)

def etl_post(path, identifiers=None, post_data=None):
    def date_handler(obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            raise TypeError
    json_data = json.dumps(post_data, default=date_handler) if post_data else None
    return _request(path, identifiers, json_data)

def _request(path, identifiers=None, post_data=None, method=None):
    data = None
    try:
        url = urlparse.urljoin(settings.ETL_WEB_API_URL, path)
        if identifiers is not None:
            for o in identifiers:
                url += "/" + str(o)
        if post_data:
            url += "/"
        request = urllib2.Request(url, data=post_data)
        request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        request.add_header("X-ETL-Authorization", settings.ETL_WEB_API_KEY)
        if method:
            request.get_method = lambda: method
        result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        data_str = result.read()
        if result.getcode() == 200:
            data = json.loads(data_str)
        else:
            logger.error("Unexpected response %s" % result)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e.message)
    return data
```

Also, I tried `result = urllib2.urlopen(request, data=post_data)`, no success.

`post_data` example:
`{"project_id": "nYhRTAmGkkHSlLr8BfPR", "project_name": "rocket-launch", "salt": "805b2892c16369275eerec4dd401f5f", ...}`

```
(Pdb) type(post_data)
<type 'str'>
```

**Receiver part**, app 2 view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_project_data(request, trust_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pdb.set_trace()
```

The arrived message:

```
(Pdb) request
<WSGIRequest: POST '/pipeline/get_project_data/2/'>

(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending JSON, not form-encoded data. That is found in `request.body`, not `request.POST`.

I must say though, if these two apps are in the same project there are much easier ways of sending data between them than by making HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes, you are right `request.body`, thank you. Can you give me an example of alternative data sending method between Django apps?